# How to get Google Pay Public Key for Direct Integration

Tags: android, kotlin, payment-gateway, google-pay

I am trying to integrate google pay in my android app. I found official integration guide [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial). I want to integrate google pay without any payment gateway in between (DIRECT method).

I found DIRECT method integration code [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#tokenization) in DIRECT tab. In that google asks for `protocolVersion` and `publicKey` as parameter and below i found that i can get my public key in my `Google Pay Developer Profile`. I searched for Google Pay Developer Profile signup but I cannot find the way to signup for Google Pay Developer Profile and to get my public key.

Anyone can help me to get public key for google pay DIRECT integration?

Comment: Did you check it? https://developers.google.com/pay/api/

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi Yes, i have gone through all the related links of official sites and also visited the link that you sent but i didn't found any helpful document or link.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting#gateway-validity

Comment: it includes your answer

Comment: All of the explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327500/where-is-google-pay-developer-account-and-how-to-generate-public-key-to-upload-i/58457094#58457094

Answer (score 1):

I've looked up the integration on Google Pay.

You as merchant are creating the key pair used yourself by using OpenSSL as described here: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#using-openssl

After the creation you can manage your public keys within the google developer backend by following this instructions: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#key-rotation

That said, the whole process is described in the article on that site:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography

Just follow those steps. :)

Comment: Can you please explain from the screen shots of will i create a private key and then a public key .. using my ( Terminal on MAC ) or google developer account ??????I have already gone through those links .. here is the question i have posted . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327500/public-key-from-google-pay-developer-profile-for-direct-integration . .. Please have a look at it and tell me what exactly i need to do ..

Comment: Your answer is a bit help ful here .. though the second paragraph .. I need a bit more elaboration .. pictures would be a lot helpful ..

Comment: I'll check it out and see if I can provide more detailed information. :)

Comment: FYI, I provided an answer to @Rakesh's question that goes into the process in a little more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58457094/12031739

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have to register your account and pass some sort of validation like said in this page :
**https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/setup**

Have you done any of the steps required ?

Answer (score 0):

All of the explanation here : About how to generate GPay public key and whtat and where is google pay developer profile -- [Where is Google pay Developer account and how to generate public key to upload in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327500/where-is-google-pay-developer-account-and-how-to-generate-public-key-to-upload-i/58457094#58457094)